# Starting notebook from text mode

Tags: kernel, initialization

I am trying to start new notebook from a command line mode with command `UsingFrontEnd@CreateDocument[]` The notebook is created but it stays in minimized mode at the taskbar. How to start notebook properly from a command line so I can interact with it?

**Edit**

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 and I am starting the mathematica kernel in `gnome-terminal` with command `math`.

Comment: The question is not clear. What OS are you running? When you say command line, what application is actually prompting and processing your commands? A terminal emulator? A _Mathematica_ kernel?

Answer (score 3):

Using a package file

**open.m**

```
Needs["JLink`"];
$FrontEndLaunchCommand = FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "Mathematica.exe"}];
UseFrontEnd[CreateDocument[]];
```

from a command line (Windows)

```
cd \Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.4
start MathKernel -noicon -initfile C:\myPath\open.m
```